# Flat data with struct type vs document store

Tags: database, mongodb, struct, google-bigquery, couchbase

I know this is a 'soft' question, which is usually frowned upon on SO, but I have been using BigQuery to do data analysis on (obviously) flat data, which contains both structs and repeated data. Let's just use a very basic example, a row might look like this:

- ID
- Title (`str`)
- ReleaseYear (`int`)
- Genres (`str[]`)
- Credits (`struct[]`)

And an example piece of data might look like:

```
{
    "ID": "T-1997",
    "Title": "Titanic",
    "ReleaseYear": 1997,
    "Genres": ["Drama", "Romance"],
    "Credits": {
        "Actors": ["Leonardo DiCaprio", "Kate Winslet"],
        "Directors": ["James Cameron"]
    }
}
```

My question is basically what type of operations or queries can be done in a native document store, such as MongoDB or CouchBase, that couldn't be done in a relational DB that supports arbitrarily-nested data. In other words, my assumption (and I hope I'm wrong or misguided) is that as long as a DB supports structs, it can do everything that a document-store can do. If not, what are some places where it is either: (1) something that can be done in MongoDB (or any other document-store) that cannot be done in BigQuery (or any other database that supports structs)? and (2) something that can be done **much more easily** in MongoDB that in a relational DB?

Comment: This questions might be more appropriate over at https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what type of operations or queries can be done in a native document
> store, such as MongoDB or CouchBase, that couldn't be done in a
> relational DB that supports arbitrarily-nested data.

Even if does support arbitrarily nested data, BigQuery allows limited nesting compared to MongoDB .MongoDB supports more levels of nesting.
In BigQuery, your schema cannot contain more than 15 levels of nested STRUCTs. MongoDB supports unto 100 levels of nesting for BSON documents.

> In other words, my assumption (and I hope I'm wrong or misguided) is
> that as long as a DB supports structs, it can do everything that a
> document-store can do.

Not exactly - nested columns are columns within columns. But sharding in an RDBMS is a complex endeavor compared to a NoSQL database like Mongo. Technically you can do, but it wasn't designed for the same purpose. Its like using a wrench as a hammer - sure you can, but its purpose was something different. You should use the right tool for the right purpose.

> If not, what are some places where it is either: (1) something that
> can be done in MongoDB (or any other document-store) that cannot be
> done in BigQuery (or any other database that supports structs)? and
> (2) something that can be done much more easily in MongoDB that in a
> relational DB?

The crux of the matter is, an RDBMS may tack on features to "technically" allow you to do some things that you can do in a NoSQL database. But it doesn't mean it may work just as well. For example, because of the features that make an RDBMS an RDBMS (ACID compliance, transactions etc), there will always be an additional performance hit compared to a NoSQL database. If an RDBMS removes these features, then it is no longer an RDBMS!

This answer illustrates how MongoDB achieves better performance because it doesn't need to support RDBMS features :

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/54373/when-would-someone-use-mongodb-or-similar-over-a-relational-dbms

> - MongoDB has a lower latency per query & spends less CPU time per query because it is doing a lot less work (e.g. no joins,
>   transactions).
> - As a result, it can handle a higher load in terms of queries per second and is thus often used if you have a massive # of users.
> - MongoDB is easier to shard (use in a cluster) because it doesn't have to worry about transactions and consistency. - MongoDB has a
>   faster write speed because it does not have to worry about
>   transactions or rollbacks (and thus does not have to worry about
>   locking).
> - MongoDB does not have a schema in case you have a special use case that can take advantage of that.

Another feature is sharding - sharding is easier with mongodb because it doesn't need to support many of the features which make an RDBMS an RDBMS, such as being ACID compliant. In contrast, sharding is complex for an RDBMS because an RDBMS must remain ACID compliant.

Take a look at the following two images:

[image]

[image]

The speed boat would out perform the "amphibious car" in the water 10/10 times. The amphibious car technically can navigate in water, but it wasn't designed to, hence is much slower and unsuited for its purpose.

[image]

Like wise, look at the difference in aerodynamics of the speed boat and this sweet automobile. Even if you tacked on wheels to the boat, its not going to perform as well as this car on land. (As an analogy you could say that NoSQL databases don't do joins - you have to implement them yourself. - but will it perform better than an RDBMS for join heavy operations ?)

The point I'm making with the analogies, is that each kind of database was initially designed for a specific goal, and over time features have been added to try and make it solve problems it was not designed for (hence it doesn't do it as well as something specifically designed for that purpose).

Hence in your question, even if BigQuery or some RDBMS *can do something*, *it doesn't mean that you should use them for the job*. The same applies for NoSQL databases. You should use the best tool for the job.

Comment: great answer, thanks for taking the time. I've awarded you the bounty. Out of curiosity, would you want to show an example in code/querying where something is difficult in a relational DB that would be trivial to do in a noSQL store?

Comment: @Thanks David. To answer your question, it isn't that querying anything in a relational DB is difficult - in fact querying in a relational DB should be easier for most things because you have the benefit of joins, etc and a powerful language. The difference is that performance in a NoSQL DB may sometimes be faster than an RDBS because a of the lack of transactions etc. For example, in an RDBMS, it is easy to write a query with a join. In a NoSQL DB you need to write joins your self. Regarding performance, arbitrary queries in a NoSQL DB could be faster because there are no transactions.

Answer (score -1):

Disclaimer: I don't have experience in MongoDB or CouchBase. My answer is based on BigQuery's capability on STRUCT.

- Performance

  BigQuery's STRUCT is optimized for query. For example, if you query `select a.nested_b.nested_c.nested_d from table_t`, the query only scans data for the left STRUCT field `nested_d`, it is fast and cheap.
- Usability

  If your data is write-once or append-only, then STRUCT column is comparable with document store AFAIK.

  But if you want to update only certain nested field later, nested STRUCT makes it pretty difficult to do, because there is no way to update single item in REPEATED field, you have to load the whole array, scan and change, and repack to update a column. You will be writing something like:

```sql
UPDATE table
SET Credits.Actors = (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(...) FROM UNNEST(Credits.Actors) WHERE ...)
WHERE ...
```

It may become a bigger problem when there is array of struct of arrays (and even more nested levels). Based on my understanding of document store, updating single nested field of a document should be easier than this. Basically, this is kind of the price you have to pay to get the performance benefit mentioned earlier.

Comment: Document-oriented databases can be optimized for query too. For example, Couchbase and MongoDB both support indexes for optimized queries.